# java eclipse hadoop map reduce program unable to access my files stored in hdfs

Tags: file, hadoop, input, microsoft-distributed-file-system

My java eclipse hadoop map reduce program is displaying an error unable to locate the input file. I had copied the files to hadoop directory via terminal using hadoop commands. I can see the files in java eclipse dfs location. And also using the command hadoop dfs -ls in terminal. When i created a normal folder (not hdfs) then the problem get solved. But then program is accesing the file from local file system. 
I had installed hadoop 1.2.1 on redhat server 32 bit, using java eclipse luna, i had already included hadoop plugins and external jar files from the hadoop library. Input and output path are given through run time arguments

Answer (score 1):

First of all,Hadoop eclipse plugins doesn't have great reliability. I had the same problem when using the plugin with the *Eclipse Luna*. But that compatibility issue got solved when i used Eclipse Juno. And there is no suitable plugin available for Hadoop 2.x versions. 
You can use the tool ***Maven*** to manage all the Hadoop dependencies just like Hadoop eclipse plugin except that you should run the Job from the terminal.

[Link on how to use Maven with Hadoop](https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/setup-maven-project-for-hadoop-in-5mn/)

Accept my answer if it fits your case. :)